# SSRS 2008 - Error in exporting to Excel with the number of columns

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS 2008 report that is successfully running in production for quite some time. Its a simple tablix report with static number of columns (50). We have used the Pagebreak property to split it into multiple sheets. The problem is its throwing an error while exporting to excel - *An error occurred during local report processing.
Excel Rendering Extension: Number of columns exceeds the maximum possible columns per sheet in this format; Columns Requested: 281, Max Columns: 256* 
I wonder if this is because of the number of rows although that doesn't make sense because its only got about 900 rows. Any thoughts about why this is happening? Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks,
Aparajith

Comment: Are you sure it only has 50 columns? The error message is quite exact.

Comment: Yes the number of columns is fixed to 50. The report neither has any matrix nor any column groups in it.

Comment: it's a table report? if so, what width are the columns set to in properties? Also do you have any other objects in your report?

Comment: Yes its just a table report. The columns have normal widths (mostly 1in for most of them). There's only one dataset and about 8 tables each with a filter on it displaying different pieces of the data returned by the dataset.

Comment: Exactly 1 inch? SSRS tends to merge columns when exporting to excel, there is no way to stop this behaviour, but you can reduce it by doing some things (like reducing the number of decimal places in a column width, making sure your items are lined up, make sure the report boundrys are moved up to your objects, check the value for left under the Location section in the properties window is set to zero)